# How to delete last row from a table without conditions?

Tags: sql

I have a table where all rows are already in necessary order. I need to delete the very last row from this table. How?

For example, I cannot use

```
order by
```

because the rows are already in the right order.

I need something like

```
delete bottom(1) from mytable
```

Comment: How is the order defined?

Comment: sample data and table columns required!!

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last row of a table" in a relational database

Comment: "rows are already in the right order" <-- no they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables represent *unordered* sets. There is no ordering to the table, so there is no "first" row and there is no "last" row. There is no "right order". That is simply how SQL works.

In order to define a "last" row, you need a column that specifies the ordering. Often, this will be an auto-incremented id, so the last row would have the largest id.

If you have such a column and are using MySQL then you can use `limit` and `order by` with `delete`:

```
delete t from <table> t
    order by t.id desc
    limit 1;
```

If you do not have such a column, you will need to identify the row you want to delete through other means:

```
delete t from <table> t
    where col1 = ? and col2 = ? and . . .;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product supports `ORDER BY`  for a `delete` statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . MySQL at least.  That is odd, I'm surprised I put in a MySQL answer when there isn't a MySQL tag.  I'm usually careful about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below SQL query to delete last record,

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID in(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable)
```

You must require either `WHERE` or `ORDER` clause to delete last record.

Answer (score 0):

If you have id column and set it to auto increment you can use this:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```